# What is robotic meat used for?

Tags: futurama

In the episode [31st Century Fox](http://theinfosphere.org/31st_Century_Fox) there is a scene where Bender goes to a robotic butcher shop. There we see the robot butcher chop a robot pig and grind it into a robotic sausage.

What could this robotic meat be used for?

Comment: Robots dining would be my first guess...

Comment: Thats the joke... What WOULD robotic meat be good for? Nothing!

Comment: It's used as a punchline.

Answer (score 3):

Since the material in question is from Futurama, an absurd comedy cartoon, it is natural that the answer might be equally absurd.  Going off into an almost purely speculative direction, it might be safe to say that Robots might have self repair mechanisms which would require "raw" material in the form of complex circuits, alloys, and non-traditional robot oils that could be processed through the use of robotic "digestion" to be re-purposed for robotic functions.  So, much like how Robots must "drink" alcohol in order to maintain their power levels, they might need to eat robotic food in order to maintain their mechanical components.

**OR...**

It could just be a joke.